# Is there a way to combine 2 or more RSS feeds using RegEx in Yahoo Pipes

Tags: rss, yahoo-pipes

For example:

```
sitefeed1/rss/q=$q
sitefeed2/rss/q=$q
sitefeed3/rss/q=$q
```

Where "$q" matches the query and the new feed output would be something like:

```
newcombinedyahoopipesfeed/rss/q=$q
```

I'm not familiar with Yahoo Pipes, other than knowing it works pretty good with feeds.

Can someone show me an example? If possible, thanks!

Comment: What query? Also there's no regex in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Find the example pipe below
http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.edit?_id=5691296436921897d50d218c27defb85

What it does?
1) Uses a 'fetch feed' module to get the three rss feeds... This will get all three feeds and combine them.. all items of feed1 will appear first, then all for second and then for third

2) Uses a sort module to rearrange all items such that latest items come on the top, mixing items from all three feeds

However please not the output url is not what you assumed!!! it will be similar to http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?_id=5691296436921897d50d218c27defb85&_render=rss